# Int stack implementation

Tags: c, stack, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Stack {
  int value;
  int is_empty;
  struct Stack *next;
};

int pop(struct Stack **stack) {
  if ((*stack)->is_empty == 1) {
    printf("Stack is empty!\n");
    abort(); // not sure what this does
  } else {
    int value = (*stack)->value;
    // outer pointer (static) points to new stack now
    *stack = (*stack)->next;
    return value;
  }
}

void push(struct Stack **stack, int value) {
  // malloc is used so this memory can be accessed outside of scope
  struct Stack *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack*));
  if (head != NULL) {
    head->value = value;
    // head's next is pointer to stack
    head->next = *stack;
    head->is_empty = 0;
    // stack now holds pointer to head
    *stack = head;
  } else {
    printf("push memory no alloc");
  }
}

struct Stack *empty() {
  struct Stack *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack *));
  if (head != NULL) {
    head->value = 0;
    head->is_empty = 1;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
  } else {
    return NULL;
  }
}

int main() {
  struct Stack *init = empty();
  struct Stack **stack = &init;
  push(stack, 3);
  push(stack, 2);
  push(stack, 1);
  int one = pop(stack);
  printf("one: %d\n", one);
  int two = pop(stack);
  printf("two: %d\n", two);
  int three = pop(stack);
  printf("three: %d\n", three);
  //int hmm = pop(stack);
}
```

I'm not sure pointers to pointers is the best way to do this. I also feel like I'm writing code in a Java-y way, and would like to know how to improve my C style.

Also, are there any edge cases I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Things you did well:

- Overall the code looks very nice and well organized.
- You used comments well.

## Things you could improve:

#### Syntax:

- `typedef` your `struct`s.

  > ```
  > struct Stack {
  >   int value;
  >   int is_empty;
  >   struct Stack *next;
  > };
  > ```

  The `typedef` means you no longer have to write `struct` all over the place. That not only saves some space, it also can make the code cleaner since it provides a bit more abstraction.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      int value;
      int is_empty;
      struct Stack *next;
  } Stack;
  ```
- You can simplify your `NULL` checks.

  > ```
  > if (head != NULL)
  > ```

  Since `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0`, we can treat is as a comparison to `0`, making the `!= NULL` a redundant check.

  ```
  if (head)
  ```
- If you don't take in any variables as parameters, you should declare them as `void`.

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```

#### Error handling:

- Don't use [`abort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abort/).  The function raises the `SIGABRT` signal. This, if uncaught, causes the program to terminate returning a platform-dependent unsuccessful termination error code to the host environment. The program is terminated without destroying any object and without calling any of the functions passed to `atexit` or `at_quick_exit`.  It would be much better to return an error indicator and have the calling function handle it.

  ```
  return -1; // we have an error
  ```

#### Memory usage:

- You never `free()` your `init` value.

  > ```
  > struct Stack *init = empty();
  >
  > // within empty()
  > struct Stack *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack *));
  > return *head;
  > ```

  You should probably `free()` it before your program terminates.  Failure to deallocate memory using `free()` leads to buildup of non-reusable memory, which is no longer used by the program. This wastes memory resources and can lead to allocation failures when these resources are exhausted.

  ```
  free(init);
  ```

#### Returning:

- You don't `return` a value from `main()`, even though you state you do.

  > ```
  > int main() {
  >     // no return value... no indication of successful exit
  > }
  > ```

  `Return`ing `0` is usually a typical indication of a successful exit.

  ```
  return 0;
  ```

Comment: I also never free `head`, in `push`. Should I do that, and if so, where? EDIT: That may be a stupid question. Rather, should I be freeing memory in pop somewhere?

Comment: @dysruption You `return` the allocated memory (`head`) and assign it to `init`, so `init` is the only variable you have to `free()`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1305785/1937270) for more clarification.

Comment: how about in pop? is there dead memory there?

Comment: @dysruption When you `typedef` your `struct`, and get rid of all the superfluous `struct` text, you will get a warning: "Incompatible pointer types assigning to `struct Stack *` from `Stack *`".  I'll leave that up to you to fix though.

Comment: I did not receive that warning. Which line would have triggered it?

Comment: @dysruption Lines 18 and 29.  If compiling with GCC, enable compiler warnings with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 5):

Your calls to `malloc(sizeof(struct Stack *))` are wrong.  That does *not* allocate enough memory to hold one stack element.  Rather, it allocates enough memory to contain one pointer.  You want `malloc(sizeof(struct Stack))`.

You provide `push()` and `pop()`, but those two operations aren't enough to make a useful stack.  At the minimum, you should also provide an `is_empty()` function.  Otherwise, it wouldn't be fair to expect users to know when it is safe to pop an element.  (They would have to keep track of the stack size themselves, which means that your data structure isn't doing its job.)  Also consider adding a `peek()` function.

I find that `empty()` is an odd name for a constructor.  Something like `new_stack()` would be clearer.

The stack, being a data structure, acts as a "library".  To remain generic and reusable, library code should avoid having side effects.  In particular,

- Calling `abort()` is antisocial.  If you detect an error, then you should return an error code.  As an alternative, an assertion might be acceptable.  Another crappier alternative would be to not check at all, and just declare that popping an empty stack has undefined behaviour (i.e., it probably crashes).  Calling `abort()` is odd in that you are expending effort to detect the error, but deliberately taking an action that violates expectations of how a library should behave.
- Don't print error messages.  If you *must* print something, print to `stderr` to avoid contaminating the output.

In this case, I think that returning an error code would make the interface too much of a pain to use.  Using an assertion would be the way to go, in my opinion.

Comment: I appreciate it. In my pop function - do I need to free the memory of the initial Stack? Or does it get deallocated after there is no longer a reference to it?

Comment: Nothing in C is automatic. Every pointer returned by `malloc()` must eventually be `free()`d. Otherwise, it's a memory leak. So yes, you have a memory leak in `pop()`.

Comment: How does [this](http://pastebin.com/1tbz5kUL) look?

Comment: Better! I suggest that you pose it as a second question on Code Review. Mention that it is a follow-up to this question.