# Singly linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management, interface

Header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct linked_list linked_list;
typedef struct cons cons;

void append(cons *cons, int value);
void linked_list_append(linked_list *ll, int value);
int size(linked_list *ll);
void insert_after(cons *c, int value, int index, int current);
void linked_list_insert_after(linked_list *ll, int value, int index);
void delete(cons *c, int index, int current);
void linked_list_delete(linked_list *ll, int index);
linked_list *new_linked_list(void);
void linked_list_destroy(linked_list *ll);
void destroy(cons *c);
int get(cons *c, int index, int current);
int linked_list_get(linked_list *ll, int index);
void cons_print(cons *c);
void linked_list_print(linked_list *ll);
```

Actual code:

```
#include "ll.h"

struct cons {
  int value;
  cons *next;
};

struct linked_list {
  int size;
  cons *list;
};

linked_list *new_linked_list(void) {
  linked_list *ll = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
  assert(ll);
  ll->size = 0;
  ll->list = NULL;
  return ll;
}

int linked_list_get(linked_list *ll, int index) {
  assert(ll);
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(index <= (ll->size - 1));
  return get(ll->list, index, 0);
}

int get(cons *c, int index, int current) {
  if (index == current) {
    return c->value;
  } else {
    return get(c->next, index, ++current);
  }
}

void linked_list_append(linked_list *ll, int value) {
  assert(ll);
  (ll->size)++;
  if (ll->list) {
    append(ll->list, value);
  } else {
    cons *new = malloc(sizeof(cons));
    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    ll->list = new;
  }
}

void append(cons *c, int value) {
  if (c->next) {
    append(c->next, value);
  } else {
    cons *new = malloc(sizeof(cons));
    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    c->next = new;
  }
}

void linked_list_insert_after(linked_list *ll, int value, int index) {
  assert(ll);
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(index <= (ll->size - 1));
  ll->size++;
  insert_after(ll->list, value, index, 0);
}

void insert_after(cons *c, int value, int index, int current) {
  if (index == current) {
    cons *new = malloc(sizeof(cons));
    new->value = value;
    new->next = c->next;
    c->next = new;
  } else { 
    insert_after(c->next, value, index, ++current);
  }
}

int linked_list_size(linked_list *ll) {
  if (ll) {
    return ll->size;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

void linked_list_delete(linked_list *ll, int index) {
  assert(ll);
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(index <= (ll->size - 1));
  ll->size--;
  delete(ll->list, index, 0);
}

void delete(cons *c, int index, int current) {
  if (index == current) {
    cons *temp = c;
    *c = *(c->next);
    free(temp);
  } else {
    delete(c->next, index, ++current);
  }
}

void linked_list_destroy(linked_list *ll) {
  if (ll) {
    destroy(ll->list);
    free(ll);
  }
}

void destroy(cons *c) {
  if (c) {
    destroy(c->next);
    free(c);
  }
}

void linked_list_print(linked_list *ll) {
  assert(ll);
  cons_print(ll->list);
}

void cons_print(cons *c) {
  if (c) {
    printf("%d ", c->value);
    cons_print(c->next);
  } else {
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  linked_list *new = new_linked_list();
  linked_list_print(new);
  linked_list_append(new, 2);
  linked_list_print(new); // 2
  linked_list_append(new, 3);
  linked_list_print(new); // 2 3
  linked_list_append(new, 4);
  linked_list_print(new); // 2 3 4
  linked_list_insert_after(new, 15, 1);
  linked_list_print(new); // 2 3 15 4
  linked_list_delete(new, 1);
  linked_list_print(new); // 2 15 4
  printf("get 0: %d\n", linked_list_get(new, 0));
  printf("get 2: %d\n", linked_list_get(new, 2));
  printf("get 1: %d\n", linked_list_get(new, 1));
  linked_list_destroy(new);
  return 0;
}
```

1. I'm trying to split up my code into a code file and a header file, but it doesn't feel right. I'm not actually hiding any of the implementation details from the client if they can see the helper methods. What's the correct way to do this?
2. My `delete` function works, but I don't really understand it. Previously the meat of it was

   ```
   if (index == current) { cons *temp = c; c = temp->next; free(temp); }
   ```

   but this didn't work. Why?
3. I've tried to incorporate style / memory advice I've gotten in my previous submissions [stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42834/int-stack-implementation) and [binary search tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42931/binary-search-tree-implementation). I don't think there are any memory leaks, but I'd like some double checking.

Any and all criticism is welcome here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not actually hiding any of the implementation details from the client if they can see the helper methods. What's the correct way to do this?

Define the helper <strike>methods</strike> functions in the C file:

- Define them before (higher/earlier in file) than the public functions, so that the public functions have seen them before they're compiled
- Define them lower/later in the C file, but put their declarations at the top of the file

And, define them as `static`: that way they're not visible outside the C file (the linker doesn't create public symbols for them, therefore not only client code hasn't seen them in the header file, but also the linker won't permit client code to link to them.

For example remove `append` from the header, and write the code like this:

```
// helper for linked_list_append
static void append(cons *c, int value) {
  if (c->next) {
    append(c->next, value);
  } else {
    cons *new = malloc(sizeof(cons));
    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    c->next = new;
  }
}

void linked_list_append(linked_list *ll, int value) {
  assert(ll);
  (ll->size)++;
  if (ll->list) {
    append(ll->list, value);
  } else {
    cons *new = malloc(sizeof(cons));
    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    ll->list = new;
  }
}
```

> My delete function works, but I don't really understand it.

I don't really understand it either. It says,

```
void delete(cons *c, int index, int current) {
  if (index == current) {
    cons *temp = c;
    *c = *(c->next);
    free(temp);
  } else {
    delete(c->next, index, ++current);
  }
}
```

... which means ...

- If we have found the node we want to delete
- copy the contents of the next node onto this node
- free this node

I suspect that it seems to work only because you access memory after it has been freed, which is illegal but which may not be visible unless/until other software is doing more malloc/free which cases the freed memory to be overwritten.

Try the following and see whether it still works:

```
cons *temp = c;
*c = *(c->next);
// it shouldn't matter what's in the memory being freed
// because we're not allowed to use it again after feeing it
memset(temp, 0 sizeof(cons));
free(temp);
```

The problem/solution with deleting a node from a singly-linked list is:

- You must search the list to find the node to be deleted
- Before to delete the node, you must adjust the pointers so that the previous node points to the next node

Something like this (untested code ahead):

```
void linked_list_delete(linked_list *ll, int index) {
  assert(ll);
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(index <= (ll->size - 1));
  ll->size--;
  cons *found;
  if (index == 0)
  {
    // delete first node on the list
    // list must point to the next node
    found = ll->list;
    ll->list = found->next;
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i = 0, cons* prev = ll->list; ; ++i, prev = prev->next)
    {
      if (i+1 == index)
      {
        // next node is the one we want to delete
        found = prev->next;
        // adjust pointers to point to the one beyond it
        // so we don't break the chain when we remove found
        prev->next = found->next;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  free(found);
}
```

It's a bit hard to do this with recursion because to delete the current node you need to be able to adjust the previous node.

Comment: I think I fixed delete and cleaned up the code rather well. How does [this](http://pastebin.com/Z3Us0wcr) look ?

Answer (score 3):

Several things that stick out to me at a glance:

- What is `cons`?  Don't you mean `Node`?  At first I thought it was just a short form of constructor, but it appears to be corresponding to a node.
- I'd strongly recommend using a different variable name other than `new`.  Although this is C and not C++, this could still cause confusion, both to the reader and to the compiler (also notice the syntax-highlighting in the posted code).  It'd be even more problematic if this happened to be compiled with a C++ compiler.  You could just rename it to something like `newList`.
- You should rename `delete()` to something else not corresponding to the equivalent C++ keyword.  Also, I'm not sure what exactly this function is for, even from looking at the name.  You already appear to have two functions that destroy nodes, so I'm not sure if this one is needed.  If it is needed, then give it a more accurate name.
- In `linked_list_destroy()`, you should have a `while` loop, not an `if` statement.  The loop should manually `free()` each node, one at a time.  You also don't need `destroy()`.  Just have the one function that performs the aforementioned procedure.

Comment: `cons` is the Racket equivalent of Lisp's `car`, which I have some experience in.

Comment: @dysruption: Okay.  Make sure that is clarified in the code, if it requires explanation.

Comment: Why is the `while` loop better than the recursive strategy? Sure, you use fewer functions, but I think it's clearer code. Does the general C consensus contradict me on this?

Comment: @dysruption: That's generally how it's done, and it's also quite clear.  Even if you did stay with recursion, [it could still be done with just one function](http://breakinterview.com/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/).

Comment: [`cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) is common jargon in functional programming languages. For instance, in Haskell the `(:)` function which prepends an element to a list is pronounced "cons" (the function appends to a list is "snoc").

Answer (score 2):

You could consider consolidating your code by using pointers-to-pointers. Here's some untested but heavily commented code showing the idea.

```
void linked_list_append(linked_list *ll, int value) {
  /* Acquire a pointer to the pointer to the beginning of the list. 'it' stands for
   * 'iterator' because it's used for iterating the list. */
  cons **it = &ll->list;

  /* Walk the list, making 'it' point to every 'next' pointer in the list until
   * we find a 'next' pointer which is null (denoting the end of the list).
   */
  while ( *it ) it = &it->next;

  /* Make the null 'next' pointer point to a new 'cons' element. */
  *it = malloc(sizeof(cons));
  (*it)->value = value;
  (*it)->next = NULL;

  /* Bump the size of the list by one. */
  ++ll->size;
}
```

It may be a good idea to get a pen and paper and draw something involving boxes and arrows to see how this works.

Comment: But my ll is a pointer to a pointer, in effect, no? It holds a pointer to the first cons of the list at all times, and that cons can hold a next cons, etc.

Comment: @dysruption No, a pointer to a pointer is something which has two `*` characters in it's type. e.g. `int **`. The type of `ll` is `linked_list *`. It's a pointer to a struct.

Comment: I'm confused. My code that you site only occurs if the current `ll->list` is `NULL`. If it's not, it calls `append`, which walks the list and appends to the end.

Comment: @dysruption Oops, you're right - I'll adjust my answer. Thanks for pointing that out!